# Angular ng-show not showing the right div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried to make one page application in which you are in overview and when you click on an item, you get detailed page with information.

Now the first time when you click the on the item, it does show the details and closes overview. Even when you hit back button, it closes details and opens overview again. But then you cant go back to detail anymore. what am I doing wrong?

This are my divs

```
<div class="col-xs-12 alertSidebar">
      <div class="omgevingsalertOverview" ng-show="activeWindow=='overview'">
        >>> LIST OF ITEMS
      </div>
      <div class="alertDetail" ng-show="activeWindow=='detail'">
        <button ng-click="activeWindow = 'overview'">Ga terug</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is what i do in the controller

```
$scope.activeWindow = "overview";
function showFeatureDetails(featureId){
  $scope.featureId = featureId;
  $scope.activeWindow = "detail";
}
```

The showFeatureDetails function is called when you click an item or on a marker in Google Maps

**UPDATE**

When I do `console.log($scope.activeWindow)` in the showFeatureDetails  It first prints out overview, than i go to details it prints details when i go back to overview it still prints details. So its like the ng-click on the button doesnt affect the scope?

**UPDATE 2**

It works now. What I did is, I changed the button click to call a function called showOverview inside my controller. And there I am changing the activeWindow.

Complete code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 alertSidebar">
      <div class="omgevingsalertOverview" ng-show="activeWindow=='overview'">
        >>> LIST OF ITEMS
      </div>
      <div class="alertDetail" ng-show="activeWindow=='detail'">
        <button ng-click="showOverview()">Ga terug</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

in the controller

```
function showFeatureDetails(featureId){
  $scope.featureId = featureId;
  $scope.activeWindow = "detail";
  $scope.$apply()
}

$scope.showOverview = function(){
  $scope.activeWindow = "overview";
}
```

Comment: Where have you called the function `showFeatureDetails` in UI

Comment: in Google Maps, when you click on a marker it runs the showFeatureDetails function

Comment: it sounds like the `showFeatureDetails` function will not run again after you've opened the detail pane once. Can you check that by loggin anything to the console inside the function?

Comment: it does, cause when I do console.log(featureId) I get the feature ID. please see my updated question

Comment: since you are calling the function from a 3rd party API such as google maps, `$scope.$apply()` will come into play. `function showFeatureDetails(featureId){
  $scope.featureId = featureId;
  $scope.activeWindow = "detail";
 $scope.$apply()
}` may do it

Comment: still not changing the activeWindow after the first time :(

Comment: __when i go back to overview__, what you mean by this?

Comment: I mean when i press the button which changes the activeWindow

Comment: I got it working now. see updated question plz